# why am I getting Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I've this call

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("/allMovies/allMovies.txt")
Call<List<Movies>> getAllMovies();
```

and this json

```
{
movies: [
{
id: "1000",
name: "Suicide Squad",
year: "2016",
category: "action",
},]}
```

with this model:

public class Movies {

```
private String id;
private String name;
private  String year;
private String category;
```

why am i getting

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: I am not getting it: Your JSON has one object, not an array. Additionally, it is invalid, as the keys are not double-quoted.

Comment: i've more ```{
id: "1000",
name: "Suicide Squad",
year: "2016",
category: "action",
}``` it's a list of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the response of the request, you'll notice that it doesn't return just **a list of movies** but **an object that has a list of movies inside**. So, basically, you need to create a class like this:

```java
class MoviesListResponse {
    private List<Movie> movies;
}
```

and use it as a return type of your request.